# Coldfusion 9 Flash Form Not Responsive in Safari 5

Tags: flash, coldfusion, safari, cfform

I have some simple code with two inputs and a submit button, which works in Chrome and Firefox, but is completely unresponsive in Safari. It doesn't let me enter text, and the Submit button seems inactive. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
    @charset "utf-8";

    body {
        background-color: #ccc;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 80%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #main {
        width: 798px; /* same as your cfform's width value */
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>


<CFIF NOT ISDEFINED("FORM.SUBMIT")>
    <div id="main">
        <cfform format="flash" action="" skin="haloorange" width="798" height="540" style="background-color: ##999999; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 38px;">
            <cfformgroup type="panel" label="APPLICATION" width="790" style="background-color:##DDDDDD;">
                <CFINPUT label="First Name" TYPE="Text" NAME="fname" MESSAGE="First Name required." value="Ahmed" REQUIRED="Yes" tooltip="Enter your first name." width="298">
                <CFINPUT label="Last Name" TYPE="Text" NAME="lname" MESSAGE="Last Name required." value="Osman" REQUIRED="Yes" tooltip="Enter your last name." width="298">
                <CFINPUT TYPE="submit" size="49" NAME="submit" value="Submit" tooltip="Save your name.">
             </cfformgroup>
        </cfform>
    </div>
<CFELSE>
    <cfdump var="#FORM#">
</CFIF>

</body>
</html>
```

I feel like there's nothing wrong with my code, simple as it is, and I've tried going even simpler--It looks like Coldfusion cannot generate a working flash form in Safari, but that seems like too large an error to go unnoticed on the Internet.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?  I logged a bug in CF 8 that was eventually fixed that affected Flash Forms on Google Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Safari on Mac and I see the same as you.  The form does not render properly, you cannot enter text and a loading cursor appears.

This is most likely a bug in ColdFusion's Flash Forms.  You can log a bug with Adobe (http://bugbase.adobe.com/) if you like, but I wouldn't count on it being fixed quickly.

All that said, I would strongly persuade you to use something other than Flash Forms.  If you want a Flash based application, look into using Flex, but really, you should be using an HTML form with Javascript validation and use CSS to style it.  It will be much easier to reach cross browser compatibility.  Flash Forms have not been kept up to date and while they have not yet been deprecated I wouldn't be surprised if they were removed in a future version of ColdFusion.  Most developers do not use them.  Even if they do meet your needs, you can quickly run into their limitations.

Comment: I agree with you, and would prefer to toss CF entirely, but unfortunately I'm interning in a twilight tech firm and that type of decision isn't up to me. Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy.

Comment: Well, give CF a chance, you might be surprised.  Its a great language/tool.